# Creating WebUI for sysadmin scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, ui-automation, webui

Yes, my question may sound very vague, incomplete. Beginner to webui developement.

Looking for An interactive WebUI for SysAdmin tasks:

What I have now?

- a lot of Ansible tasks, playbooks, bash scripts, python scripts for sysadmin tasks.
- Some of them can be stored locally(in laptop or in any location)
- Some of them can be placed only where it is kept and need to run from there.

What I am trying to achieve?

I would like to add a WebUI application to support these scripts. Don't want to edit the scripts and provide the values everytime through SSH and that usual execution like `./script.sh` & `python mypy.py`.

---

Once of the Example task:

- Have backups stored in S3 and onpremise locations. Importantly, Database and some miscellaneous things. Currently I am running some bash scripts, python scripts to restore them. (need to modify some variable depends on the selected backup)

currently it shows what we have in S3 and we need to choose a backup date and list of archives and modify the restore script.
So I was thinking, why not read from s3 and other backups locations, list items as checkboxes, execute will run the current scripts and everyone is happy.

---

while googling currently available choices,

- https://github.com/bugy/script-server      >> but this application couldn't parse from my output and use it somewhere else.

---

So, what should I be learning, what all things I will require to implement this solution (pythonic way preferred)? Maybe this could be a big ask.

I was thinking about Django or any php based framework?

I would like that to be a easy development. :D

Answer (score 1):

Removing Flask, Django from my list.

Going ahead with `python streamlit`. Meet the requirements and easy to implement with existing python scripts.